# Facebook events no longer sync with my Windows Phone calendar. How can I fix this?

Tags: calendars, facebook

When I create an event in Facebook, it used to automatically appear on my calendar, but it doesn't anymore.  Are there any settings I can change or has this feature been disabled?

Comment: No, there is still support for that.

Answer (score 2):

1. Remove the Facebook account from your Phone.
2. [Remove the Facebook account from your Microsoft Account](https://profile.live.com/cid-2301a8a572db03a7/Services/?view=manage).
3. [Add the account to your Microsoft Account](https://profile.live.com/cid-2301a8a572db03a7/Services/).
4. Add the account to your Phone.

Comment: @Matt, was this solution working for You?